# TextView in Gridlayout appearing out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android application for displaying contact details of all the services which are available in my city. I am using drawer in my application for navigation of cities. But TextView having longer text (e.g. Adress) goes out of the screen. So please help me so that TextView should be fit in the screen.
Below is my code for that activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Name: "
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Idea Gallery"
    android:id="@+id/textView28"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Address: "
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Shop No 5, Akshay Apartment, Kalwa, Thane - 400605, Opposite Pramila Hospital "
    android:id="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Contact:"
    android:id="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="022 - 38539146"
    android:id="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:textSize="22dp" />
</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I could use Relative layout / linear layout for this ..do you definitely want to do this in GridLayout

Comment: No, I will use any layout in which all components appeared properly.

Comment: since you wrote application for displaying...i think using webview with runtime generated html is one of the best option for displaying...since in this case you can make a better looking design in a easy way for displaying...

Comment: @NADIMSHAIKH: Did you get the answer for this. I also stuck in same issue?

Comment: @SagarTrehan I had change design of my application. Sharan was right, GridLayout is not right layout for this type of design pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following attributes to your `TextView` elements:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
```

This will make the `TextView`s fill the cell's width, and not further.

I applied it on the gray labels here:
[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your TextView's

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

What this does is , If your Text  is long it will show it in dots.
for Example : Nadim Shaikh will be Nadim SH...

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I want to display all the text within the screen

Comment: Do you want all the text in a single line??

Comment: Change your textview layout_width=match_parent. You will display the full text then

Answer (score -1):

The best way in android to do something like that is to use html during Runtime...

For example in xml just keep a WebView inside Relative layout..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in the java code do this:

```
String name="...",address="...";
Webview web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
 String html = "<html>\n" +
               "<body>\n" +
               "<h4>Name:</h4>" +  //name as heading 
                name +     // here the name you like to add
               "\n" +
               "<hr>" +
               "<h4>address</h4>" + //address as heading 
               address +   //here the address you like to add
               "\n" +
               "<hr>" +  //line
               "</body>\n" +
               "</html>";
//in this same way you can add as many items you want
web.loadData(html, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

I know you wish to achieve this by using some layout in xml, but i believe this is the best way, because in this case you can make a better design also..
and in run time you can add name , address and contact as many as you want..